# JSXgraph not moving points when I change a function

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I'm using JSXgraph to show students limsups and liminfs. The version works here - http://ibldynamics.com/exercises/ex2_56.html

Here's the code:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 40px;">
        <p style="display: inline;">N:</p>
       // Create a slider for the values of N
        <input id="NSlider" type="range" min="1" max="19" value="1" step="1" style="width: 50%;">
        <p style="display: inline;"><span id="NOut"></span></p>
        <script>
            // Get the value of N from the slider
            var NSlider = document.getElementById("NSlider");
            var NOutput = document.getElementById("NOut");
            NOutput.innerHTML = NSlider.value; // Output value for student to see
        </script>
    </div>
    <!-- Create board with points -->
    <div id="box" class="jxgbox" style="width:500px; height:500px;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Create board
            var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {
                boundingbox: [-1, 2, 21, -0.2],
                axis: true,
                grid: true
            });
            // Generate points in the sequence and graph points of the sequence
            var i;
            var s = [null];
            for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                s.push(1 + Math.pow(-1, i) / i);
                board.create('point', [i, s[i]], {
                    color: 'yellow',
                    fixed: true,
                    withLabel: false
                });
            }
            // Genereate liminfs and limsups
            var infs = [null],
                sups = [null];
            for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                infs.push(Math.min.apply(null, s.slice(i + 1)));
                sups.push(Math.max.apply(null, s.slice(i + 1)));
            }
            // Graph liminf and limsup points
            var liminf = board.create('point', [
            function() { return NSlider.value; },
            function() { return infs[NSlider.value]; }], {
                color: 'blue',
                withLabel: false
            });
            var limsup = board.create('point', [
            function() { return NSlider.value; },
            function() { return sups[NSlider.value]; }], {
                color: 'orange',
                withLabel: false
            });
     
            board.update()
        </script>
    </div>
        <script>
            // Set board to update when the N slider is updated
            NSlider.oninput = function () {
            NOutput.innerHTML = this.value; // Output value for student to see
                liminf.moveTo([NSlider.value, infs[NSlider.value]]);
                limsup.moveTo([NSlider.value, sups[NSlider.value]]);
            }
        </script>
```

The problem is the version I have here - http://ibldynamics.com/exercises/ex2_57.html

I've only changed two things. The function that I use to generate the points is `s.push((-1)**i*(1 + (1 / i)));` and the bounding box is a little bigger. For some reason the blue points won't show up any more.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does `u` and `v` mean in your plot? How do we calculate it?

Comment: In the text on the website, u_N are the elements of the array infs, and v_N are the elements of the array sups

Comment: The blue dot is present on the DOM, but some script is setting the `display: none; visibility: hidden;` styles to it. You have to debug that.

Comment: I added `visible: true` to the point on the board, and it didn't fix the issue. Any idea why it would do that when I change the function that populates s?

Comment: I've identified the issue. If the value in either sups or infs is negative, the moveTo function doesn't show the point.

Comment: You need to set `display: unset; visibility: true`. only visibility won't make any difference.

Comment: Just a minor comment: The event handler to the input event can be simplified to
`NSlider.oninput = function () { NOutput.innerHTML = this.value; board.update(); }`

The two points `liminf` and `limsup` are already tied to the slider.